# How to change Data Grid script output colors in TOAD?

Tags: toad

How can I change the color of TOAD data grid? It seems that I have changed it somehow by mistake and I can not find a way to revert the colors to original one. This is a sample of color that I am currently seeing http://link.sheidaei.com/moidp

I am using Toad for Oracle version 12.0.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should be be to change the data grid colors under 'Toad Options' (menu 'View/Toad Options'). Select branch 'Data Grids/Visual' and 'Styles'. All this in TOAD 12.1.

Answer (score 9):

do these steps in Main Menu:

1. View /Toad Options
2. Data Grids/Visual
3. Styles/Active Style
4. select your proper style from drop down.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow 5 steps like the below picture:
[image]